# Representation of so(11) in terms of tensors

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm going through some lecture notes I found online about Symmetry for Physicists and I got stuck in a problem of representations and tensors. The problem reads "The Lie algebra so(11) of rotations in 11 dimensions has an irreducible 55-dimensional representation.
Describe the representation module in terms of tensors." I've been thinking about it for a while but I'm not able to relate it to the simpler cases I found in the notes. Could someone provide me with a starting point?
Thank you

Comment: Hint: Have you considered 11(11-1)/2=55 ? This is the adjoint representation, an antisymmetric 2-tensor.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I can't understand it. What do you mean?

Comment: Do you know how to represent the adjoint of *any* SO(N)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No

Comment: The representation you are looking for is precisely the adjoint representation $\mathfrak{so}_n = \bigwedge^2 V$ where V is the "fundamental" n-dimensional representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  defining representation generators of *SO(n)* are *n×n* antisymmetric real matrices $M_{ij}$, so, then, *n(n-1)/2* of them, where *i,j*=1,...,*n*. Recall the generators you know from *n=3*.

For *n=11*, you then have 55 such matrices, the dimension of the *so(11)* algebra. The real structure constants of the commutators of these 55 matrices, $M^a_{ij}$, now indexed by *a=1,....,55*,  among themselves$^1$, are the representation matrices of the adjoint representation, $f^a_{bc}$. They act on  the space of 55-vectors, easy to construct from the rank-2 antisymmetric tensors $M_{ij} $.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>$[M_b,M_c]=f^a_{bc}M_a.$</sub>